# Use of RabbitMQ C# with AMQ/QPID & WSO2 Message Broker Fanout Exchange

Tags: rabbitmq, amqp, wso2, qpid

I am using RabbitMQ 2.8.7 DotNet Client along with WSO2 MB 3.2.1.
My deployment environment is either Win7 R1 64bit or Win Server 08 R2 64bit.
I have run into issues with multiple connections to the Exchange whereby data that is streamed to multiple consumers is lost at intermittent times.  We have attempted to update WSO2 MB to 3.2.3 & change our exchange to a fanout to resolve this loss of connectivity, but have run into issues.

It would "appear" that this link is somewhat related:

http://wso2-oxygen-tank.10903.n7.nabble.com/Qpid-Authorization-handler-does-not-allow-to-subscribe-td2080.html

I first wanted to find out if this is the correct approach.

Secondly, I wanted to understand the current error we are receiving at run-time with the use of the fanout as we cannot access the data.  Below is the error received, the WSO2 MB log output & a code snippet from the producer.

Please inform if more information is required to pinpoint.

Error Received...

```
 "Unhandled Exception:
RabbitMQ.Client.Exceptions.OperationInterruptedException: The AMQP operation
was interrupted: AMQP close-reason, initiated by Peer, code=504, text="org.apache.qpid.AMQSecurityException: Permission denied: binding
[error code 403: access refused]", classId=50, methodId=20, cause=
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.SimpleBlockingRpcContinuation.GetReply()
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.ModelBase.ModelRpc(MethodBase method, ContentHeaderBase header, Byte[] body)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Framing.Impl.v0_9_1.Model._Private_QueueBind(String queue,
 String exchange, String routingKey, Boolean nowait, IDictionary arguments)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.ModelBase.QueueBind(String queue, String exchange, String routingKey, IDictionary arguments)
   at RabbitMQ.Client.Impl.ModelBase.QueueBind(String queue, String exchange, String routingKey)
   at Send.Main()
```

Log @ time of error...

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/03/01 11:29:27 | [2013-03-01 11:29:27,042] DEBUG {org.apache.qpid.server.protocol.AMQProtocolEngine} -  Frame Received: Frame channelId: 0, bodyFrame: [ConnectionStartOkBodyImpl: clientProperties={platform=[LONG_STRING: .NET], product=[LONG_STRING: RabbitMQ], capabilities=[FIELD_TABLE: {publisher_confirms=[BOOLEAN: true], exchange_exchange_bindings=[BOOLEAN: true], consumer_cancel_notify=[BOOLEAN: true], basic.nack=[BOOLEAN: true]}], copyright=[LONG_STRING: Copyright (C) 2007-2012 VMware, Inc.], information=[LONG_STRING: Licensed under the MPL.  See http://www.rabbitmq.com/], (http://www.rabbitmq.com/%5D,) version=[LONG_STRING: 0.0.0.0]}, mechanism=PLAIN, response=[0, 115, 118, 99, 46, 114, 105, 46, 97, 116, 99, 0, 112, 97, 115, 115, 119, 111, 114, 100], locale=en_US]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/03/01 11:29:27 | [2013-03-01 11:29:27,042]  INFO {org.apache.qpid.server.handler.ConnectionStartOkMethodHandler} -  SASL Mechanism selected: PLAIN
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/03/01 11:29:27 | [2013-03-01 11:29:27,042]  INFO {org.apache.qpid.server.handler.ConnectionStartOkMethodHandler} -  Locale selected: en_US
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/03/01 11:29:27 | [2013-03-01 11:29:27,681]  INFO {org.apache.qpid.server.handler.ConnectionStartOkMethodHandler} -  Connected as: svc.abc.def
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/03/01 11:29:27 | [2013-03-01 11:29:27,681]  INFO {org.apache.qpid.server.handler.ConnectionStartOkMethodHandler} -  Framesize set to 65535
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/03/01 11:29:27 | [2013-03-01 11:29:27,681] DEBUG {org.apache.qpid.server.protocol.AMQProtocolEngine} -  Frame Received: Frame channelId: 0, bodyFrame: [ConnectionTuneOkBodyImpl: channelMax=256, frameMax=65535, heartbeat=0]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/03/01 11:29:27 | [2013-03-01 11:29:27,681] DEBUG {org.apache.qpid.server.protocol.AMQProtocolEngine} -  Frame Received: Frame channelId: 0, bodyFrame: [ConnectionOpenBodyImpl: virtualHost=carbon, capabilities=null, insist=false]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/03/01 11:29:27 | [2013-03-01 11:29:27,697] DEBUG {org.apache.qpid.server.protocol.AMQProtocolEngine} -  Frame Received: Frame channelId: 1, bodyFrame: [ChannelOpenBodyImpl: outOfBand=null]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/03/01 11:29:27 | [2013-03-01 11:29:27,697]  INFO {org.apache.qpid.server.handler.ChannelOpenHandler} -  Connecting to: carbon
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/03/01 11:29:27 | [2013-03-01 11:29:27,697] DEBUG {org.apache.qpid.server.protocol.AMQProtocolEngine} -  Frame Received: Frame channelId: 1, bodyFrame: [QueueDeclareBodyImpl: ticket=0, queue=fanout, passive=false, durable=false, exclusive=false, autoDelete=false, nowait=false, arguments=null]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/03/01 11:29:27 | [2013-03-01 11:29:27,759]  INFO {org.apache.qpid.server.handler.QueueDeclareHandler} -  Queue fanout bound to default exchange(<<default>>)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/03/01 11:29:27 | [2013-03-01 11:29:27,759]  INFO {org.apache.qpid.server.handler.QueueDeclareHandler} -  Queue fanout declared successfully
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/03/01 11:29:27 | [2013-03-01 11:29:27,759] DEBUG {org.apache.qpid.server.protocol.AMQProtocolEngine} -  Frame Received: Frame channelId: 1, bodyFrame: [QueueBindBodyImpl: ticket=0, queue=fanout, exchange=fanout, routingKey=null, nowait=false, arguments=null]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/03/01 11:29:27 | [2013-03-01 11:29:27,759]  INFO {org.apache.qpid.server.protocol.AMQProtocolEngine} -  Closing channel due to: org.apache.qpid.AMQSecurityException: Permission denied: binding  [error code 403: access refused]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/03/01 11:29:27 | [2013-03-01 11:29:27,759]  INFO {org.apache.qpid.server.AMQChannel} -  No consumers to unsubscribe on channel [/192.168.1.14:56087(svc.abc.def):1]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/03/01 11:29:27 | [2013-03-01 11:29:27,775] DEBUG {org.apache.qpid.server.protocol.AMQProtocolEngine} -  Frame Received: Frame channelId: 1, bodyFrame: [ChannelCloseOkBodyImpl: ]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/03/01 11:29:27 | [2013-03-01 11:29:27,775]  INFO {org.apache.qpid.server.protocol.AMQProtocolEngine} -  Channel[1] awaiting closure - processing close-ok
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/03/01 11:29:27 | [2013-03-01 11:29:27,775]  INFO {org.apache.qpid.server.handler.ChannelCloseOkHandler} -  Received channel-close-ok for channel-id 1
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/03/01 11:29:29 | [2013-03-01 11:29:29,070] DEBUG {org.apache.qpid.server.protocol.AMQProtocolEngine} -  Frame Received: Frame channelId: 0, bodyFrame: [ConnectionCloseBodyImpl: replyCode=200, replyText=Connection close forced, classId=0, methodId=0]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/03/01 11:29:29 | [2013-03-01 11:29:29,070]  INFO {org.apache.qpid.server.handler.ConnectionCloseMethodHandler} -  ConnectionClose received with reply code/reply text 200/Connection close forced for /192.168.1.14:56087(svc.abc.def)
```

I have found this problem to also occur when attempting to connect with Java as well.
A brief example of the C# code for the producer is below:

```
class Send {

    public static void Main() {

        string serverAddress = "amqp://" + "192.168.1.12" + ":5672/carbon"; 

            ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();

            factory.Uri = serverAddress;

            using (IConnection connection = factory.CreateConnection())

            using (IModel channel = connection.CreateModel()) {

            channel.QueueDeclare("fanout", false, false, false, null);

            channel.QueueBind("fanout", "fanout", "");

            string message = "Hello World!";

            byte[] body = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

            channel.BasicPublish("", "hello", null, body);
            Console.WriteLine(" [x] Sent {0}", message);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In WSO2 MB the exchanges will not be created dynamically for any name given.Therefore to get this work with 'fanout' exchange,it needs to be pre-declared in qpid-virtualhosts.xml file. Else use the default exchange of WSO2 MB.

It seems you haven't correctly declare the exchange name for which the queue needs to be bound. If it it for Queues, default exchange name declare would be like,

```
 ch.ExchangeDeclare("amq.direct", "direct");
```

If it is for topics, `

```
 ch.ExchangeDeclare("amq.topic", "topic");
```

Please refer [this](http://isharapremadasa.blogspot.com/2013/08/using-wso2-message-broker-with-rabbitmq.html) blog post for using a sample .Net/C# Consumer/Publisher client with WSO2 Message Broker.`